# Can't get setParameter to work in XSLT transformer

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Trying to pass a parameter to a XSLT stylesheet. Here is my java code...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, TransformerException {
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    String filename = "MyFile.xml";
    Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("MyXSL.xsl"));
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
    transformer.setParameter("dynevidence", filename);

    Source text = new StreamSource(new File(filename));
    transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("output.html")));
}
```

Here is my XSLT sheet

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
    <xsl:param name="dynevidence"/>
    <B>Description</B>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Nothing is outputted for the parameter and the markup goes straight to Description.  Any ideas what I a doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare `<xsl:param name="dynevidence"/>` as a top-level child of `xsl:stylesheet`, then where you want to use the value use `$dynevidence`.